# Dini's theorem (specific case)

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, summation, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

**Note:** I asked this question before but it wasn't well written, So I deleted my previous question and re-wrote it.

According to **Dini's theorem**:

> If $X$ is a compact topological space, and $\{ f_n \}$ is a monotonically
>   increasing sequence (meaning $f_n(x) \leq f_{n+1}(x)$ for all $n$ and $x$) of
>   continuous real-valued functions on $X$ which converges pointwise to a
>   continuous function $f$, then the convergence is uniform.
>
> The same conclusion holds if $\{ f_n \}$ is monotonically decreasing
>   instead of increasing.

(Note: I have proven both cases)

But, what if for every $n$ $\{f_n(x0)\}$ is monotonic but for some values of $n$ it's monotonically decreasing and for other it's monotonically decreasing.
for example; for all even values it is increasing and for non-even values it is decreasing.

**How could I prove that Dini's theorem is effective in this case?
In other words, how to prove that the convergence is uniform**

Comment: Since there were no answers to your previous postings of this question, if you have improvements to make, simply edit the question instead of deleting and reposting the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A=\{x: f_n(x) \leq f_{n+1}(x) \forall n\}$ and $B=\{x: f_n(x) \geq f_{n+1}(x) \forall n\}$. Note that $A$ and $B$ are closed sets  and hence they are also compact. Also $A \cup B=X$. $f_n \to f$ uniformly on each of these sets. Given $\epsilon >0$ there exist $n_1, n_2$ such that $|f_n(x)-f(x)| <\epsilon$ for all $x \in A$ for all $n >n_1$ and $|f_n(x)-f(x)| <\epsilon$ for all $x \in B$ for all $n >n_1$. Let $n_0=\max \{n_1,n_2\}$. Then $|f_n(x)-f(x)| <\epsilon$ for all $x \in X$ for all $n >n_0$.